# What are the causes for $g2$ ( intensity) value changes in a Mach-Zehnder setup at a fixed reference path and fixed sample?

Tags: optics, laser, interference, interferometry

I'm using a Multimode laser passing it through a Mach-Zehnder interferometer. I am able to get almost constant $g2$ (intensity) from the sample. However, the reference arm intensity keeps fluctuating by 40 % even when the arm is parked at a fixed path length. I tried blocking the sample arm completely but the fluctuations did not go down. I want to understand what could be the cause of this fluctuation. There is no ambient light leaking in the system.

Comment: Can you explain your optics setup in a bit more detail?

Comment: I'm using an MM laser at 808nm, in a Mach Zehnder interferometer setup. The entire setup is placed on an optical table.  I couple light into an MM fiber splitter, one arm goes to sample and the other goes to reference. I use a free-space delay line to vary the path length. The light from the reference arm is collected using one arm of the SM splitter. The other arm of the SM splitter is on the sample side and the combined signal is used to get the intensity values. During data collection, I block sample arm completely and get the measurements at different path lengths of reference arm.